# Mocking/spying on a constructor "x.Thing()"

Tags: javascript, mocking, jasmine, spy

Assuming `x` is an external library and `Thing` is an object that can be constructed from `x`. This is all wrapped in an Angular service, like so:

```
app.service('thingService', function() {
    var thing;

    this.createThing = function(thingParam){
        thing = new x.Thing(thingParam);
    }
});
```

My initial attempt included this:

```
xSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('x', ['Thing']);
spyOn(window, 'x').andReturn('xSpy');
```

But it still complains that `x() method does not exist` on that line that `Thing` should be constructed

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt

> ```
> xSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('x', ['Thing']);
> spyOn(window, 'x').andReturn('xSpy');
> ```

is wrong:

`spyOn()` replaces *methods* with spies, since `x` is an object this won't work. This is why you get the exception `x() method does not exist`.

Assuming your example you can just replace the attribute:

```
describe("Test", function() {
    var origThing;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // create spy object for Thing that provides its methods
        var mockedThingInterface = jasmine.createSpyObj('Thing', ['methodA', 'methodB']);

        mockedThingInterface.methodA.and.returnValue(1);
        mockedThingInterface.methodB.and.returnValue(2);

        // remember original constructor
        origThing = x.Thing;

        // replace the constructor
        x.Thing = function() {
            return mockedThingInterface;
        }
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // restore when finished
        x.Thing = origThing;
    });

    it("should ...", function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't seem to resolve the use of `x` in the code that's being tested (`createThing` method of the service). When I add your code to the test I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: x` when I run the test

Comment: I assumed you wanted to spy `thing`only. If you want to replace the whole `x` you could go one level up and remember `x` and replace `window.x` (in case `x` is really a global). If `x` is not a global, please clarify your example. The error you mentioned points to this.